# getting an error with linq-to-sql on a table with a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

linq-to-sql is giving me this error "Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on 'Table(Friend)' because it has no primary key." from a table with a composite primary key

Comment: Do you mean a composite primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL performs best with a single field int as a primary key. If you have a composite primary key, your best bet is to create a surrogate key for that table using a single integer field.

Comment: Downvote as LinqToSql works with composite primary keys, you do not need to add a surrogate integer when one isn't appropriate (for example if the composite key enforces the desired uniqueness of a row naturally). Instead you can manually set the 2 columns properties to `Primary Key = True` in the DBML file and LinqToSQL will work as expected.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. You can also create the surrogate and specify a unique constraint on the multiple columns. The question becomes whether or not you wish to manually manage the composite primary keys or allow LINQ-to-SQL to manage the single integer key itself. I prefer single integer primary keys myself, primarily because I'm not a fan of composite foreign keys. Your experience and preference may respectfully differ...

Comment: I completely agree with Luke.  Creating a surrogate key just to make Linq to SQL happy is not a reasonable reason.

Comment: Initially, I didn't care about being downvoted because it started out being a "to each their own" thing. Then I noticed the dates of the comments. To be downvoted four and six YEARS after the fact is the height of petty. If my answer was technically incorrect, I would understand, but it's not. If you don't want to create a surrogate key just to make Linq-to-SQL happy, don't. I don't even do it for that reason. I prefer the performance of a single integer key field rather than keying on multiple fields of varying types. Access is faster, storage footprint is smaller...my two cents.